# just the first ArrayList<String> works

Tags: java, mysql, arraylist

So I've created those two methods which are the same and they return with the IDs of chairs and the date of reservation :

```
public ArrayList<String> GetChair(String Class) throws SQLException{
      ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>(20);
      openconnection();
      String querychair = "SELECT * FROM hema.flight_usa WHERE free = 1 and class='"+Class+"'";
      Statement stm=(Statement) con.createStatement();

    ResultSet rs;
   rs = stm.executeQuery(querychair);

   while(rs.next())
   {
      arr.add(rs.getString("chair_id"));



   }
   return arr;
  }

  //---------------- The Second One ----------------------------------------

  public ArrayList<String> GetDate(String Class) throws SQLException{

     ArrayList<String> arr2 = new ArrayList<String>(20);

      openconnection();
      String querydate = "SELECT * FROM hema.flight_usa WHERE free = 1 and class='"+Class+"'";
      Statement stm=(Statement) con.createStatement();

    ResultSet rst;
   rst = stm.executeQuery(querydate); 

      while(rst.next())
   {
      arr2.add(rst.getString("res_date"));



   }
   return arr2;

  }
```

and then I call the two methods to get the data from the table
the problem is that I get only the first called method :

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    try {
        String Class=Class1Text.getText();
        Model model =new Model();


        ArrayList<String> arr1=new ArrayList<String>(20);

        arr1=model.GetDate(Class);


        jTextField12.setText(arr1.get(0));
        jTextField13.setText(arr1.get(1));
        jTextField14.setText(arr1.get(2));
        jTextField15.setText(arr1.get(3));
        jTextField16.setText(arr1.get(4));
        jTextField17.setText(arr1.get(5));
        jTextField18.setText(arr1.get(6));
        jTextField19.setText(arr1.get(7));
        jTextField20.setText(arr1.get(8));
        jTextField21.setText(arr1.get(9));


        ArrayList<String> arr=new ArrayList<String>(20);
           arr =     model.GetChair(Class);

        jTextField2.setText(arr.get(0));
        jTextField3.setText(arr.get(1));
        jTextField4.setText(arr.get(2));
        jTextField5.setText(arr.get(3));
        jTextField6.setText(arr.get(4));
        jTextField7.setText(arr.get(5));
        jTextField8.setText(arr.get(6));
        jTextField9.setText(arr.get(7));
        jTextField10.setText(arr.get(8));
        jTextField11.setText(arr.get(9));



    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Reservation.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }



}
```

this way just the GetDate method will be done

AND IT KEEPS GIVING ME THiS ERROR:

`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:638)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:414)
    at View.Reservation.jButton1ActionPerformed(Reservation.java:293)
    at View.Reservation.access$000(Reservation.java:16)
    at View.Reservation$1.actionPerformed(Reservation.java:84)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6527)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6292)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4883)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)`

Comment: Probably you have only 3 rows with the selected class in the table.

Comment: so?
what is the problem then?

Comment: The problem is what the exception message says. The problem is also **where** the exception stack trace says it is, but you chose to hide this information from us.

Comment: Of course not ... I just didn't know it would help :/
I've edited it

Comment: The problem is at line 293 of Reservation.java, in the method `jButton1ActionPerformed()`. You see, all the information you need is in the stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IndexOutOfBoundsException is thrown to indicate that an index is out of range. In your second result set you have called to get 10 results where it might only have 3 rows in the result.

Answer (score 0):

Check the size of list before get details,

```
if(arr1.size()>9){
        jTextField12.setText(arr1.get(0));
        jTextField13.setText(arr1.get(1));
        jTextField14.setText(arr1.get(2));
        jTextField15.setText(arr1.get(3));
        jTextField16.setText(arr1.get(4));
        jTextField17.setText(arr1.get(5));
        jTextField18.setText(arr1.get(6));
        jTextField19.setText(arr1.get(7));
        jTextField20.setText(arr1.get(8));
        jTextField21.setText(arr1.get(9));
}
```